# "Soft-peddle" vs. "Soft-pedal": eggcorn blunder or sly play on words?

Tags: errors, puns, eggcorn

In chat [the other day](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6754340#6754340) I asked the following question:

> "Recently I've been seeing writers using "soft-peddle" in print (in reputable publications, to boot) when I am certain the trope is "soft-pedal": anybody have an opinion on this?"

My reasoning is that the term comes from the *soft pedal* of the piano, which the musical among you will recognize as being the pedal that composers want you to use to play a passage quietly and without force.

@tchrist noted that [the OED only lists "soft-pedal"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6754364#6754364): "OED attests all three of soft pedal, soft-pedal, soft-pedalling, but not the other." @BarrieEngland agreed, and said he thought "soft-peddle" might be an [eggcorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) of "soft-pedal."

Further research on my part yielded information that "soft-peddle" is even included on [The Eggcorn Database](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/english/455/soft-peddle/), a Web site I hadn't known existed till now. The term *soft-pedal* when spoken might be thought by the listener to be related to the ["soft sell"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_sell).

The use of *soft-pedal* peaked in the middle of the last century, while "soft-peddle" began around the same time and gained a bit of currency since then, though it is still seen far less often — overwhelmingly so — than its forebear.

It gets down to this: Are we seeing a play on words or a blunder? Certainly someone with sufficient writing credentials could be given the benefit of the doubt. Yet it seems that even (or especially) the best writers might want to underscore such a subtle pun with quotes, or set it off some other way that suggests it wasn't just a typo or brain cramp. And if "soft-peddle" makes steady gains, might it not one day supplant the term that spawned it? Bonus points for anyone who can provide at least a single documented instance of "soft-peddle" being used unequivocally as a pun, not a misspelling or misapprehension.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[A Purim Shpiel By Dan Silverman](http://seedyroad.com/israelism/purim.htm) contains what is unequivocally a pun.

> Although able to build a profitable medical practice in Kingston’s Jewish quarter, Maimonides could not secure a congregation among the suspicious and inward-looking autochthonous Jewish settlement. He came to soft-peddle his rabbinical wares among the local infirm gentile population, enticing them into his book-filled ante-room with small three-cornered cookies filled with his special recipe of opiated pain-easing poppy seed paste.

By far the majority of Google results for *soft-peddle* should really be "soft-pedal", though.

Comment: This looks like a very intentional pun to me Silverman knew exactly what he was writing, IMHO.

Comment: @BillFranke Yes, the more I consider it, the less likely "soft-pedal" is and the more likely it is to be deliberate. I've removed the doubt.

Comment: Accepted and, as promised, bonus point. Sorry I waited this long, but it's been under my radar and I simply didn't notice.

Comment: I don't see that this is clearly a pun. If he were selling pianos, or perhaps bicycles, it would be a good pun to say he "soft-peddled" them. 
He's peddling, or selling, his "wares," right? As in, what a peddlar does? So how is "soft-peddle" not understood to be a soft-sell technique?

Comment: @Michelle: given that the rest of the story is filled with horrendous puns (Heymon Tosh -> Hamantashen), soft-peddle really has to be a pun.

Answer (score 1):

Terms like "hard sell" are common, even where no literal sale is contemplated. For example, the Little Feat song "Texas Twister", which was a U.S. #1 hit in 1990, contains the lyrics,

> They sure do play it hard and fast / while they sell it soft and low.

(See, e.g., [Little Feat discography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Feat_discography#Singles) and [Little Feat Texas Twister lyrics](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/891050/Little+Feat/Texas+Twister).)

Therefore, there seems to be nothing *logically* wrong with "soft-peddle" as their antonym. Whatever the origins of the phrase, "soft-peddle" is not really a malapropism. It seems at best overly pedantic to say that "soft-peddle" is incorrect, instead of merely a new(er), about-equally-correct version of an old(er) idea and term. Or at least, that's my opinion, and well-explained disagreement is welcome.

Comment: This doesn't prove that it is not an eggcorn, though: it is a defnining characteristic of eggocorns that they sort of make sense.